# Tableau - How do I create multiple custom SQL from the same data source WITHOUT join?

Tags: sql, oracle, tableau-api

I need to create a dashboard which showcases a number of charts coming from the same data source.

To have the different charts, I need to create multiple custom SQLs. However every time I do that tableau will prompt me to join the tables. I do not want to join the tables as the table will otherwise be too large.

Any help will be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If the same columns are used for different charts but the number of records vary, then this could be done: 
In the custom sql query create a column naming as Col_ws and update it with unique name. Repeat this for other worksheet logic and create a union in custom sql query itself. When it comes to tableau worksheet, use that Col_ws dimension as a context filter for different worksheets.

If the columns vary for different worksheets, above approach can't be taken. So have to create different custom sql queries (data sources) for different worksheets.

Let us know if this works!